# Opencart payment extension only available to admin

Tags: php, opencart

What would be the best approach to testing the checkout (placing a test order) using a payment extension such as "Free Checkout". Although so that this payment extension is only available to the admin, e.g works the same as maintenance mode when admin logged in they can select the Free Checkout?

Or is there another way without modify the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/catalog/model/payment/free_checkout.php`

Find

```
if ($total <= 0) {
```

change it to

```
if ($total <= 0 || !empty($this->session->data['user_id'])) {
```